# Resizing UITextView Without Losing Constraints

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextview, constraints, autolayout

I'm trying to figure out how to resize UITextView (and everything actually) without losing constraints. Basically, I'm trying to layout a page where most components can have variable sizes (like description). I tried doing it with a simple use case where I have a UITextView and a UIButton underneath. I want to make sure that the position of the button is relative to the bottom of the UITextView.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
    int height = self.textView.contentSize.height;
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.textView.frame = frame;
}
```

What I ended up with is UITextView overlapping with UIButton. After doing a bit of research, it seems that if I replace the frame, all constraints are gone also. I tried copying the constraints over, but of course the pointer is still pointing at the old frame so that didn't help at all.

Is there a good way to solve a very dynamically laid out page? I'm trying to at least use interface builder rather than code everything.

### EDITED

I tried updating the constraint as suggested, but that didn't actually resize the UITextView. Did I do it incorrectly? When I get the constant again, it's updated, but the height isn't changed visually. I did simplify my code by adding an IBOutlet for the constraint. Still no luck however.

```
int height = self.textView.contentSize.height;
self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
```

### EDITED 2

I figured it out now. I had an extra constraint for the bottom and that was stopping me from actually resizing the UITextView.

Comment: I added UITextView and UIButton using Interface Builder. As for resize, it's done in the code as shown above. Can you give me an example of how to change the constant of a constraint? The only way I know how to resize is to mess with the frame. I will try to adjust the constraint. I assumed I will have to iterate and find it?

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work btw. Take a look at the edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you've defined your button's top constraint. If it's to the label, when you adjust the label's height constraint, the button will move. For example, if doing it programmatically:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:label];
label.text = @"Hello world";

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:button];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label, button);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[label]-[button]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
[label addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

Then, if you change the label's height constraint, the button will move:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

If you've defined your UI in Interface Builder, select the button and check the top constraint of the button and make sure it's to the label, not the superview:

[image: top constraint]

But, again, if the button's top constraint is to the label, when the label's height constraint changes, the button will move.

Comment: I actually ran into another case where even though I changed the constraint, it doesn't resize. I can make it bigger and smaller as many times as I want. Then after a while I can't change the constraint anymore. Can you think of a reason for this? It's definitely running through the same code.

Comment: @juminoz That could be for a bunch of reasons (perhaps your constraint's `IBOutlet` hasn't been hooked up, perhaps you have conflicting constraints, perhaps you're doing some of this on a queue other than the main queue, etc.). You'd have to share more (e.g., your full set of constraints and `IBOutlet` references for all of the subviews on your view; the code for changing the constraint constants; etc.) for us to comment meaningfully on this topic. Perhaps do a simple project and upload it somewhere so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Sure. I will create a simple project and let you know. I made sure everything is hooked up and I tried to eliminate constraint one-by-one until there really wasn't anything left, but it still wasn't working. My current case has to do with UIView and UITableView that stack on top of each other. UIView can change size based on conditions and I want to make sure that UITableView is automatically resized to make room.

Comment: Here's a simple projected hosted on DropBox (created using XCode5, targeting iOS7 btw). I added some code to change the constraint in viewDidAppear of viewController.m. Based on this simple example, I'm a little doubtful that it can be done without manipulating frames. In my actual project, I'm able to expand the UIView most likely because both of them are contained within a UIScrollView instead of UIView. In this sample project, you will find that if you add height constraint for both UIView and UITableView, the app won't even launch.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28512995/Layout2.zip

Comment: I just saw that the small view wasn't linked properly also. However, after I fixed it, the resizing part still doesn't work.

Comment: There were three problems I see in that storyboard: 1. the little view has an `IBOutlet` to the view controller's root view; that outlet has to be removed (otherwise you have two outlets to the root view, which explains the erratic behavior I saw); 2. the little view does not, though, have an `IBOutlet` to `theView`, which I assume you intended (though, technically, is not required for the problem at hand); 3. most critically, the size constraint does not have an `IBOutlet` linked up, either.

Comment: @juminoz See https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11739737/Layout2.zip for my attempt to remedy these three issues.

Comment: Just saw your other comments. I'm not sure how things got unlinked actually. It seems to work now in my project also. I will try the same thing in my actual project and see how it goes. Thanks!